# Calling a GWT RPC function from Python-mechanize

Tags: python, gwt, gwt-rpc

I am getting a 500 : Internal error, the payload of the POST is *definately* right, one thing I noticed is the Content-Type is not "sticking" using `b.addheaders = [('Content-Type',"text-x-gwt-rpc")]` -- and I'm not sure why.

Does anyone have quick/dirty code used to access a GWT RPC (i.e. emulate the GWT client) in Python using mechanize.  Browser?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use GWT-RPC from non-GWT solutions, the format is internal and subject to change without notice. Consider RESTifying the app (or use SOAP and reuse the existing code of the methods, but care needs to be given to the interface definitions).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is GWT requires the content-type to be x-gwt-rpc; rather than                   'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'; which is hard coded in _http.py in the mechanize library.

Quick and dirty hack is to change this to text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=UTF-8 -- I'm sure this could be done better by subclassing AbstractHTTPHandler; maybe someone else could contribute a quick way to do that.